# ignore the error for the urls which are not in routes-laravel4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have following routes

```
Route::get('categories', 'MixsController@listJokesCategories');
Route::get('tag', 'MixsController@listJokestags');
Route::get('jokes', 'MixsController@listJokes');
```

so my valid urls are

```
site_url/categories
site_url/jokes
site_url/tags
```

**if user hit other url from browser say site_url/stories it will throw error**

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
open: /var/www/dagonlife_web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php
```

this looks very unprofessional, isnt there some way to catch this error and redirect to some custom page like **page_not_found**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you can use `App::missing()`. An example from [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-404-errors):

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

You could also listen for that specific exception and bind it to a function, e.g.:

```
App::error(function(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $exception, $code)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```